# How to Pass Parameter to array.map()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to map values to a function that will accept two numbers to multiply but am having trouble doing so (if this doesn't make sense, take a look at the examples below).

I have an array of numbers and I would like to double/triple/quadruple... the values of this array. I have created functions that would do this, and am feeding these `double()` and `triple()` into `map()`.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function double(num) {
  return num * 2;
}

function triple(num) {
  return num * 3;
}

console.log( arr.map(double) );
console.log( arr.map(triple) );
```

This solution is not scalable as what if I want to multiply the values by 5, or 10? I need a more abstract function that would take a parameter of what to multiply. I am confused about how to do this. My attempt so far is:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function multiply(num, multiplyBy) {
  return num * multiplyBy;
}

console.log( arr.map(multiplyBy(4) ); // Uncaught TypeError: NaN is not a function
```

How would I pass `multiply()`  the `multiplyBy` parameter?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do something called <strike>a factory</strike> currying. Effectively, you make a function that will return another function which is tailored to your needs. In this case, an anonymous one.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function multiplyBy(scale) {
    return function(num){
        return num * scale;
    }
}

console.log( arr.map( multiplyBy(4) ));
```

This works because the scope of the anonymous function that is returned is within that of the <strike>factory</strike> outer function. So, whenever we produce a new function, it will retain the value of `scale` that was given for its production.

Edit: The last part of @Bergi 's answer is the same as mine. The concept is apparently called currying. Thanks @Bergi ! The Factory pattern is more often applied to the production of objects, as Bergi noted, but it was the only thing I could think of at the time, and javascript sort of treats functions like objects. In this specific case, they are effectively similar. [Here is a good reference for currying in JavaScript](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)

Comment: I would use the term "factory" only for functions that return objects.

Comment: I made my answer more readable, I used the weird indentation only to make the transformation to the ES6 arrow function one-liner more obvious.

Comment: This answer is easier to understand than using `.bind`

Answer (score 23):

You're looking for [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). It can be done with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for example (or a number of helper functions that come with functional libraries, like [in Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#partial)):

```
arr.map(multiplyBy.bind(null, 4))
```

however a simple arrow function would be easier:

```
arr.map(x => multiplyBy(4, x))
```

But you can also get the partial application for free if you [curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) your `multiplyBy` function, taking the multiplier and returning a new function:

```
function multiplyBy(multiplier) {
  return function(num) {
    return num * multiplier;
  };
}
// ES6 arrow functions:
const multiplyBy = multiplier => num => num * multiplier;

arr.map(multiplyBy(4));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to create a new function with bound arguments. For example

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function multiplyBy(multiplyBy, num) {
  // note the "num" argument must come last if it is to represent the argument from "map"
  return num * multiplyBy;
}

console.log( arr.map(multiplyBy.bind(null, 4)) ); // null is for the "this" argument
```